# Selecting a Group of Radio Buttons by Clicking on Button

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna add on two `buttons` which can function as selecting all the `radio buttons` according to the respective type. I want the buttons to select either all `Yes` radio buttons or all `No` buttons accordingly.

I would appreciate if anyone could help me to solve this. Prefers JavaScript instead of jQuery.

```js
function Calc() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    var radios = document.getElementsByName("group" + (i + 1));

    for (var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
      var radio = radios[j];

      if (radio.value == "Yes" && radio.checked) {
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
      }
    }
  }

  //Display the total value of test points
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showdata" align="center"></div>

<form id="radioForm" method="get" align="center">
  <table style="width:60% table-layout:fixed" align="center">

    <!--Attributes of table. Colspan used to insert sub-title for the main title.-->
    <h3>
      <B>Initial (On Arrival)</B>
    </h3>
    <table class="table1" style="width:60%" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th>Test Points</th>
        <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time (Seconds)</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>Value</b></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>Yes</b></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>No</b></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group1"> <!--label is used to control the respective group of radio buttons-->
    <td>Initial (On Arrival)</td>
 <!--The input box in the 'Value' column is set as below-->
    <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="19" align="center" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="6" size="4"/></td>
 <!--The check boxes of 'Yes' and 'No' is created as below-->
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group2">
    <td>Drop Test (Portable Only)</td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty2" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group3">
    <td>Power Up Test (Mobile Only)</td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="0" align="center" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group4">
    <td>User Interface Room</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="161" align="center" name="qty" id="qty4" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>

    <h3>
      <B>Extreme Temperature (Cold Temp)</B>
    </h3>
    <table class="table2" style="width:60%" align="center">

      <tr>
        <th>Test Points</th>
        <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time (Seconds)</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>Value</b></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>Yes</b></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>No</b></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group5">
    <td>ATE Labview RF Testing Extreme</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="153" align="center" name="qty" id="qty5" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group5" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group5" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group6">
    <td>User Interface Extreme</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="161" align="center" name="qty" id="qty6" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group6" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group6" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group7">
    <td>Mic Talk Internal Extreme</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="68" align="center" name="qty" id="qty7" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group7" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group7" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group8">
    <td>Mic Talk External Extreme</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="53" align="center" name="qty" id="qty8" maxlength="4" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group8" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group8" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group9">
    <td>Desense Test</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="50" align="center" name="qty" id="qty9" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group9" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group9" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group10">
    <td>Tx Stability</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="43" align="center" name="qty" id="qty10" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group10" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group10" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group11">
    <td>Microphonic Test</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty11" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group11" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group11" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>

    <button type="button" name="selectYes">Select All Yes</button>
    <button type="button" name="selectNo">Select All No</button>
    <br><br>
  </table>
</form>

<table class="resultsTbl" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="total" id="total" align="center" /> Seconds</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: So, your saying you want to be able select one of the no radios, and for it to select the other ones?

Comment: You're not even showing us an attempt to accomplish the task you request. Looks like you're just wanting us to write the code for you. I see that you counted how many checkboxes are checked. Why would your requested task be any more difficult? `onclick` you just loop over and say `Element.checked = true;` or `Element.checked = false;`.

Comment: @RobertDickey I want it to select all the radio buttons.

Comment: @PHPglue Thanks for the feedback. I would've attempted if only I had the idea. That was why I headed over here. So sorry but will take this advice and surely next time will try to attempt before I ask something. Thanks a bunch once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```
function selectAll(value) {
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[value=" + value + "]");
   elements.forEach(function(element, index) {
       element.checked = true;
   });
}
```

```js
function Calc() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    var radios = document.getElementsByName("group" + (i + 1));

    for (var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
      var radio = radios[j];

      if (radio.value == "Yes" && radio.checked) {
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
      }
    }
  }

  //Display the total value of test points
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}

function selectAll(value) {
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[value=" + value + "]");
  elements.forEach(function(element, index) {
    element.checked = true;
  });
}

document.getElementById("selectYes").addEventListener("click", function() {
selectAll("Yes");
});

document.getElementById("selectNo").addEventListener("click", function() {
selectAll("No");
});
```

```html
<div id="showdata" align="center"></div>

<form id="radioForm" method="get" align="center">
  <table style="width:60% table-layout:fixed" align="center">

    <!--Attributes of table. Colspan used to insert sub-title for the main title.-->
    <h3>
      <B>Initial (On Arrival)</B>
    </h3>
    <table class="table1" style="width:60%" align="center">
      <tr>
        <th>Test Points</th>
        <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time (Seconds)</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>Value</b></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>Yes</b></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>No</b></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group1"> <!--label is used to control the respective group of radio buttons-->
    <td>Initial (On Arrival)</td>
 <!--The input box in the 'Value' column is set as below-->
    <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="19" align="center" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="6" size="4"/></td>
 <!--The check boxes of 'Yes' and 'No' is created as below-->
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group2">
    <td>Drop Test (Portable Only)</td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty2" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group3">
    <td>Power Up Test (Mobile Only)</td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="0" align="center" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group4">
    <td>User Interface Room</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="161" align="center" name="qty" id="qty4" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>

    <h3>
      <B>Extreme Temperature (Cold Temp)</B>
    </h3>
    <table class="table2" style="width:60%" align="center">

      <tr>
        <th>Test Points</th>
        <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time (Seconds)</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>Value</b></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>Yes</b></td>
        <td class="cent"><b>No</b></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group5">
    <td>ATE Labview RF Testing Extreme</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="153" align="center" name="qty" id="qty5" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group5" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group5" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group6">
    <td>User Interface Extreme</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="161" align="center" name="qty" id="qty6" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group6" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group6" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group7">
    <td>Mic Talk Internal Extreme</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="68" align="center" name="qty" id="qty7" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group7" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group7" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group8">
    <td>Mic Talk External Extreme</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="53" align="center" name="qty" id="qty8" maxlength="4" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group8" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group8" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group9">
    <td>Desense Test</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="50" align="center" name="qty" id="qty9" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group9" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group9" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group10">
    <td>Tx Stability</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="43" align="center" name="qty" id="qty10" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group10" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group10" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <label id="group11">
    <td>Microphonic Test</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty11" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group11" value="Yes"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group11" value="No"></td>
  </label>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br><br>

    <button type="button" name="selectYes" id="selectYes">Select All Yes</button>
    <button type="button" name="selectNo" id="selectNo">Select All No</button>
    <br><br>
  </table>
</form>

<table class="resultsTbl" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td class="left"><input type="text" name="total" id="total" align="center" /> Seconds</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

On click of the buttons, you can call the below function which will toggle the selection of radio buttons Yes/No based on the parameters passed.

The code gets the HTML collection of all radio buttons having `type='radio'` and `value='Yes'` or `value='No'` using **`querySelectorAll`**, then convert the HTML element collection to array using `slice`. Then updates the `checked` property to `true` using `Map` method.

```
function selectAll(value){
    var ele = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[type='radio'][value='" + value + "']"))
        .map(function (el) { el.checked = true; });
}
```

```js
function selectAll(value){
 var ele = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[type='radio'][value='" + value + "']"))
  .map(function (el) { el.checked = true; });
}
```

```html
<div id="showdata" align="center"></div>

<form id="radioForm" method="get" align="center">
 <table style="width:60% table-layout:fixed" align="center">

  <!--Attributes of table. Colspan used to insert sub-title for the main title.-->
  <h3>
   <B>Initial (On Arrival)</B>
  </h3>
  <table class="table1" style="width:60%" align="center">
   <tr>
    <th>Test Points</th>
    <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time (Seconds)</th>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="cent"><b>Value</b></td>
    <td class="cent"><b>Yes</b></td>
    <td class="cent"><b>No</b></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group1"> <!--label is used to control the respective group of radio buttons-->
     <td>Initial (On Arrival)</td>
     <!--The input box in the 'Value' column is set as below-->
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="19" align="center" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="6" size="4"/></td>
     <!--The check boxes of 'Yes' and 'No' is created as below-->
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group2">
     <td>Drop Test (Portable Only)</td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty2" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group3">
     <td>Power Up Test (Mobile Only)</td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="0" align="center" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group4">
     <td>User Interface Room</td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="161" align="center" name="qty" id="qty4" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <br><br>

  <h3>
   <B>Extreme Temperature (Cold Temp)</B>
  </h3>
  <table class="table2" style="width:60%" align="center">

   <tr>
    <th>Test Points</th>
    <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time (Seconds)</th>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="cent"><b>Value</b></td>
    <td class="cent"><b>Yes</b></td>
    <td class="cent"><b>No</b></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group5">
     <td>ATE Labview RF Testing Extreme</td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="153" align="center" name="qty" id="qty5" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group5" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group5" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group6">
     <td>User Interface Extreme</td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="161" align="center" name="qty" id="qty6" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group6" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group6" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group7">
     <td>Mic Talk Internal Extreme</td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="68" align="center" name="qty" id="qty7" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group7" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group7" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group8">
     <td>Mic Talk External Extreme</td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="53" align="center" name="qty" id="qty8" maxlength="4" size="4" /></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group8" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group8" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group9">
     <td>Desense Test</td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="50" align="center" name="qty" id="qty9" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group9" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group9" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group10">
     <td>Tx Stability</td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="43" align="center" name="qty" id="qty10" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group10" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group10" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <label id="group11">
     <td>Microphonic Test</td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty11" maxlength="6" size="4" /></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group11" value="Yes"></td>
     <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group11" value="No"></td>
    </label>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <br><br>

    <button type="button" name="selectYes" onclick="selectAll('Yes')">Select All Yes</button>
    <button type="button" name="selectNo" onclick="selectAll('No')">Select All No</button>
  <br><br>
 </table>
</form>

<table class="resultsTbl" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td>Total</td>
  <td class="left"><input type="text" name="total" id="total" align="center" /> Seconds</td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Really appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your javascript

```
var selectYesBtn = document.getElementsByName('selectYes')[0];
var selectNoBtn = document.getElementsByName('selectNo')[0];


function check_Uncheck( radioValueAttr, check ) {
    var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"[value="'+ radioValueAttr +'"]');
    for (x in radios) {
        radios[x].checked = check;
    }
}

selectYesBtn.onclick = function () {
    check_Uncheck("No",false);
    check_Uncheck("Yes",true);
};

selectNoBtn.onclick = function () {
    check_Uncheck("No",true);
    check_Uncheck("Yes",false);
};
```

The function "check_Uncheck" works for both radios (yes/no).. passing the input value attribute("Yes"/"No") as first argument, and a boolean whether to check them or uncheck them as second argument.